# Vue 3 cross-env variable is undefined

Tags: vue.js, environment-variables

I try to add an environment variable to my vuejs 3 app when I start it by npm run start:something but it does not get recognized. I have built the project, restarted the server, tried everything but if I console.log out the process.env object only NODE_ENV and BASE_URL are there VUE_APP_MODE is not.

Here is my package.json script:

```json
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "start": "npm run dev",
    "start:something": "npm run something",
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development && npm run serve",
    "something": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development cross-env VUE_APP_MODE=something && npm run serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
```

Comment: From cross-env docs (https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env): there is an example "cross-env FIRST_ENV=one SECOND_ENV=two node ./my-program". Try "cross-env NODE_ENV=development VUE_APP_MODE=something && npm run serve"

Comment: Unfortunately this does not seem to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

**You should add it to .env file when client side useage**

package.json

```
{"something": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development cross-env VUE_APP_MODE=something && npm run serve"}
```

.env

```
VUE_APP_MODE=${VUE_APP_MODE}
```

index.js

```
console.log(process.env.VUE_APP_MODE)
```